# C++ Limit the size of a dynamically allocated array or string inside a class?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Let's say I have a class that contains a pointer to string:

```
string *name;
```

Inside the constructor I would allocate memory for it:

```
*name = new string[256];
```

This way the size limit is set by the constructor, however is there a way to limit the size in the class itself at the pointer declaration?

Above is wrong!
Should be (probably)

```
*name = new char[256];
```

Comment: That's not doing what you think it's doing. This is not allocating a string with 256 characters but is allocating an array of 256 strings. Why do you need to specify a limit for string? It is dynamically sized. If you want to ensure that it is immutable, use "const string" and set its value in the constructor.

Comment: @MichaelAaronSafyan I would like the size to be constant but the content should be something I can alter throughout the program.

Answer (score 1):

It's generally not a good idea to do this. If you are trying to limit the size provided by an end user, then you should apply a limit check when receiving the input. Internally, however, you should just use `std::string` in your program with no enforcement on the size. For example:

```
 namespace {

 const int kMaxInputSize = 256;

 bool IsInputValid(const string& user_input) {
   return user_input.size() < kMaxInputSize;
 }

 // ...
 }

 // ...
```

Now, technically, you could use `char name[256]` to hard-code a string that can hold up to 256 characters (including the null terminator character), but that is incredibly error prone and ill advised.

Answer (score 0):

If your compiler supports features of the C++ 2011 Standard then you can define the class the following way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class A
{
private:    
    static const size_t N = 26;
    std::string *name = new std::string[N];
public:
    typedef size_t size_type;
    ~A() { delete [] name; }
    std::string & operator []( size_type i )
    {
        return name[i];
    }
    const std::string & operator []( size_type i ) const
    {
        return name[i];
    }
    size_type size() const { return N; }
    // Definitions of copy/move constructors and copy/move assignment operators
};

int main() 
{
    A a;

    for ( A::size_type i = 0; i < a.size(); i++ )
    {
        a[i] += char( 'A' + i % 26 );
    }

    for ( A::size_type i = 0; i < a.size(); i++ )
    {
        std::cout << a[i] << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
```

Do not forget to define destructor, copy/move constructors and copy/move assignment operators.

Also you could use smart pointer `std::unique_ptr` instead of the raw pointer.